# Spatstat - comparing spatial patterns

Tags: spatial, density-plot, spatstat

Never used R before but have spent the last few months working through Spatstat to analyse cell distributions in cancer tissue. I extract xy co-ordinates of positively stained cells for two different cell populations to generate a marked ppp. Exploring the data visually through density plots and K/G cross functions etc identifies some cases where distribution of the two cell populations are different in terms of intensity. furthermore, in some cases the cells appear to be exclusive of each other whilst other cases are characterised by 'hotspots' shared by both populations. However, I can't work out how best to demonstrate this apart from having side-by-side images as illustrations. Is there any way to integrate two density plots or create a graphic of shared regions of intensity? Or another function in Spatstat that I have missed?

Apologies if this is a silly question but struggling to progress things and would be very grateful for advice.

Regards,
Matt

Comment: Maybe it could be useful to look at relative risks of the two types. Take a look at `help(relrisk.ppp)` in `spatstat`.

Answer (score 0):

Tests for significance (= non-constant ratio of the two intensities) are provided in the `sparr` package, which extends `spatstat`. Try the function `tolerance`.